# How can I get the depth of a jpg file?

Tags: python, jpeg, imaging

I want to retrieve the bit depth for a jpeg file using Python.

Using the Python Imaging Library:

```
import Image
data = Image.open('file.jpg')
print data.depth
```

However, this gives me a depth of 8 for an obviously 24-bit image. Am I doing something wrong? Is there some way to do it with pure Python code?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: It's data.bits not data.depth.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right function? I couldn't find depth in the PIL Handbook and perhaps the return value of 8 is still correct - it could stand for "8 bits per pixel".

Comment: Yeah it's 8 bpp. What wasn't obvious (to me) was that it was for each band as per Mike's answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I don't see the `depth` attribute documented anywhere in the [Python Imaging Library handbook](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/index.htm).  However, it looks like only a limited number of [modes](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#modes) are supported.  You could use something like this:

```
mode_to_bpp = {'1':1, 'L':8, 'P':8, 'RGB':24, 'RGBA':32, 'CMYK':32, 'YCbCr':24, 'I':32, 'F':32}

data = Image.open('file.jpg')
bpp = mode_to_bpp[data.mode]
```

Comment: There are more modes this is a more complete dictionary: `mode_to_bpp = {"1": 1, "L": 8, "P": 8, "RGB": 24, "RGBA": 32, "CMYK": 32, "YCbCr": 24, "LAB": 24, "HSV": 24, "I": 32, "F": 32}`

Comment: Also some experimental modes exist: `"I;16": 16, "I;16B": 16, "I;16L": 16, "I;16S": 16, "I;16BS": 16, "I;16LS": 16, "I;32": 32, "I;32B": 32, "I;32L": 32, "I;32S": 32, "I;32BS": 32, "I;32LS": 32`

Answer (score 7):

Jpeg files don't *have* bit depth in the same manner as GIF or PNG files. The transform used to create the Jpeg data renders a continuous color spectrum on decompression.

Answer (score 4):

PIL is reporting bit depth per "band". I don't actually see `depth` as a documented property in the PIL docs, however, I think you want this:

```
data.depth * len(data.getbands())
```

Or better yet:

```
data.mode
```

See [here](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/concepts.htm) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

I was going to say that JPG images are 24 bit by definition. They normally consist of three 8 bit colour channels, one for each of red, green and blue making 24 bits per pixel. However, I've just found [this page](http://connectedphotographer.com/article/bit-depth-in-jpeg-images/) which states:

> *If you use a more modern version of Photoshop, you'll notice it will also let you work in 16-bits per channel, which gives you 48 bits per pixel.*

But I can't find a reference for how you'd tell the two apart.