# Is there a way to measure the memory consumption of a PNG image?

Tags: python, memory, png

I would like to know if there is a way in Python to measure the memory consumption of a PNG image.

For my test I've to Images `normal.png` and `evil.png`. Let's say both images are 100kb in size.

`normal.png` consists of data represented by 1 byte per pixel.

`evil.png` consists of `\x00` bytes and a `PLTE`. chunk - 3 bytes per Pixel.

For `normal.png` I could decompress the `IDAT` data chunk, measure the size and compare it with the original file size to get an approximate memory consumption.

But how to proceed with `evil.png` ?

Comment: You mean, like `width*height*depth`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Pillow` library to identify the image and to get the number of pixels and [the mode, which can be transformed into the bitdepth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1996609/918959):

```
from PIL import Image

mode_to_bpp = {'1':1, 'L':8, 'P':8, 'RGB':24, 'RGBA':32, 
               'CMYK':32, 'YCbCr':24, 'I':32, 'F':32}

i = Image.open('warty-final-ubuntu.png')
h, w = i.size

n_pixels = h * w
bpp = mode_to_bpp[data.mode]
n_bytes = n_pixels * bpp / 8
```

`Image.open` does not load the whole data yet; the compressed image in question is 3367987 bytes, 4096000 pixels and uses 12288000 bytes of memory when uncompressed; however `strace`ing the python script shows that `Image.open` read only 4096 bytes from the file in memory.