# Why does resizing the image by 50% (in pixels) does not decrease it's size by 50% in terms of KB (PIL - Pillow)?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, compression, python-imaging-library

**Tl;DR: Is it possible to manipulate size of image in KB to the desired size**?

There are 4 ways to get an image size as [answered by Mark in my another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950250/what-is-the-correct-approach-to-display-the-image-size-in-python) and I'm wondering if there's any relation of **ANY** of the size to the number of pixels?

`(7460,24300,1),(2549,6075,2),(1303,2700,3),(808,1518,4), (552,972,5)`

These are the `(os_stat_size, numpy_array_size, image_factor)`
**image_factor == factor by which the image has been resized**
As you can see the resizing factor is not proportional to the size in KB.

Code given below is working perfectly for resizing. I am experimenting on manipulating **image size in KBs** instead of pixels. I did an experiment to reduce the overall image size by 50%. The idea is that given any depth, it should be constant and the pixels should correspond to the image size in linear fashion (thinking metadata remains constant)

I did the experiment and did not get results with `jpeg`. So I thought there might be some problem with the extension as I found [this second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996577/how-can-i-get-the-depth-of-a-jpg-file) saying :

> Jpeg files don't have bit depth in the same manner as GIF or PNG files. The transform used to create the Jpeg data renders a continuous colour spectrum on decompression.

So I tried the same experiment with the `PNG` and it was same. Below are my experiments with both the versions with commented out exchange between `jpeg` and `png`

**Helper code and imports**: Working fine

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import requests
from io import BytesIO
from os import stat
import os
import sys

def resize(image:Image, current_size:tuple, new_width_height:float)->Image:
    '''
    Resize and return Given Image
    args:
        image: Image object
        current_size: Image size as (width, height)
        new_width_height = Reshaped image's width and height. If integer is given, it'll keep the aspect ratio as it is by shrinking the Bigger dimension (width or height) to the max of new_width_height  and then shring the smaller dimension accordingly 
    '''
    fixed_size = True if isinstance(new_width_height, int) else False
    w, h = current_size

    if fixed_size:
        if h > w:
            fixed_height = new_width_height
            height_percent = (fixed_height / float(h))
            width_size = int((float(w) * float(height_percent)))
            image = image.resize((width_size, fixed_height), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) # # Try Image.NEAREST

        else:
            fixed_width = new_width_height
            width_percent = (fixed_width / float(w))
            height_size = int((float(h) * float(width_percent)))
            image = image.resize((fixed_width, height_size), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS) 

    else:
        w, h = int(new_width_height[0]), int(new_width_height[1])
        image = image.resize((w,h), Image.Resampling.LANCZOS)


    return image
```

**Experiment**:

1. Actual image stats:

```
url = "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/508751.jpg"
buffer = BytesIO(requests.get(url).content)
size_buffer = buffer.getbuffer().nbytes//1024
image = Image.open(buffer)

size_uncompressed = len(image.tobytes()) // 1024

# image.save('./wallpaper.jpeg', format = 'jpeg', quality = 'keep', subsampling = False)
# size_os = os.stat('./wallpaper.jpeg').st_size // 1024
image.save('./wallpaper.PNG', format = 'PNG', quality = 'keep', subsampling = False)
size_os = os.stat('./wallpaper.PNG').st_size // 1024
numpy_size = sys.getsizeof(np.array(image)) // 1024 # same as len(image.tobytes())

print(image.size, image.format, image.mode, str(size_buffer)+' KB (buffer.getbuffer().nbytes//1024)', str(size_os)+' KB (os.stat().st_size // 1024)', str(size_uncompressed)+' KB (len(image.tobytes()) // 1024)', str(numpy_size)+' KB (sys.getsizeof(np.array(image)) // 1024)')
```

2. Resized image stats:

```
image = resize(image, image.size, max(image.size)//2)
# image.format = "JPEG" # as it'll throw error when using quality='keep' with jpeg
image.format = "PNG" 

size_uncompressed = len(image.tobytes()) // 1024


buffer = BytesIO()
# image.save(buffer, format="JPEG", format = 'jpeg', quality = 'keep', subsampling = False)
image.save(buffer, format="PNG")
size_buffer = buffer.getbuffer().nbytes//1024

# image.save('./resized_wallpaper.jpeg', format = 'jpeg', quality = 'keep', subsampling = False)
# size_os = os.stat('./resized_wallpaper.jpeg').st_size // 1024

image.save('./resized_wallpaper.PNG', format = 'PNG')
size_os = os.stat('./resized_wallpaper.PNG').st_size // 1024

numpy_size = sys.getsizeof(np.array(image)) // 1024

print(image.size, image.format, image.mode, str(size_buffer)+' KB (buffer.getbuffer().nbytes//1024)', str(size_os)+' KB (os.stat().st_size // 1024)', str(size_uncompressed)+' KB (len(image.tobytes()) // 1024)',str(numpy_size)+' KB (sys.getsizeof(np.array(image)) // 1024)')
```

None of them are actually linear. Is it normal or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: There's already a way of reducing an image to a desired size in kB here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/52281257/2836621 and here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54713865/2836621

Comment: If you have a question about something specific, please show the results your code produces and explain what you don't understand, e.g. *"I reduced the image height and width by a factor of 2, and expected..."*. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hey Mark. thanks again. I actually created my own version of Binary Search. Exact same thing but since I was regressing the test boundaries, a 7MB image takes too much time if I want to keep it under say, 300 KB..

Comment: @MarkSetchell, Thanks, I have updated the findings too.

Comment: If your factor is 2 for height and width, you'll have 1/4 of the number of pixels and 24300/4=6075, so that's correct. If your factor is 3, you'll have 1/9 of the number of pixels and 24300/9=2700, so that's correct. So, I presume your question is about the size in kB of the JPEG, so how about plotting a graph of that to show what's upsetting you?

Comment: Oh! Now that you have mentioned it, just realised it. Also, the examples you have mentioned, they compress the quality with a factor. However I on the other hand, want to keep the quality same (as you might have notices `quality='keep`) by reducing the width and height to a particular size.